# Counter with automatic increment each day

Tags: counter, increment

Hi I want a counter which increments each day by 3 or a number between 1-3.

I got the base code

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.timer').countTo({
        from: 0,
        to: 2487,
        speed: 3500,
        refreshInterval: 50,
        onComplete: function(value) {
            console.debug(this);
        }
    });
});
```

//-->

How do I implement a dynamnic increase every day?

Answer (score 0):

**One option:**

place a start day in your code, like 2015-06-20. Get the difference from that day and now (2015-06-23 - 2015-06-20 = 3). You can just multiply the difference with 3.

**Another one**

If you want to increment between 1-3 randomly and you want the increment to be saved, you need either an algorithm to calculate the factor based on a date (then you have to know the start date), or save the increment each day to database, so you can fetch it an sum it up.

Comment: An algorithm could be **mod 3 + 1**. Take the differece from a start date to now and do **mod 3 + 1**. Its not random, but if you want random increment, I think you have to save the increment to a file/ cookie/ database...

Comment: Was this answer useful for you?